# Disable hour increment/decrements when scroll past 59/00 minutes for timepicker

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

So I am using a `Timepicker` to get time to set alarm.

When you scroll past 59 minutes, the picker automatically increases the hour and vice-versa. 
I want to stop that behaviour. 
How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own dialog with two [NumberPickers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), that you control completely.

Comment: Is there no other way?